# Remove DTYPE field on hibernate select query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes "Table" and "Table1" (which extends Table), both points to the same table ("test") on DB, when I try to perform a select on all fields for this table, I got an error informing that the column "DTYPE' is unknow.

Below is my POJO first lines declaration, just to clarify, I'm not able to edit "Table" class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Table1 extends Table
```

Did someone know how can I remove this column for the hibernate query?

Below is the error that I got

> SQL error code = -206
>
> THIS_.DTYPE
>
> Column unknown